# No dual boot ,windows 7 loads up

Tags: dual-boot

I have windows 7 ent ,and i have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS from the Windows itself (Im guessing it was wubi install). It was working great via dual boot ,and i loved Ubuntu when i decided to remove windows 7 .

So i have uninstalled it using "osuninstall" from Ubuntu ,and it "removed" Windows ,when actually i got `BOOTMGR is missing` error and nothing would boot up. I finally got it fixed with Windows 7 installation DVD ,so now only Windows is loading ,without boot option for me to choose from.

How do i retreive my dual-boot selection ?

Comment: By uninstall do you mean you tried to uninstall Windows from wubi installation of Ubuntu? Not sure if I understood, you want your box with Ubuntu only or in dual boot with Ubuntu and Windows?

Comment: I have tried uninstalling windows via some tool called osuninstall that i got from apt-get in Ubuntu . When i ran it ,it offered me to choose what OS i want to remove ,so i've picked Win7 and after restart nothing came up (Not windows nor Ubuntu) . Eventually i would prefer using Ubuntu only .

Comment: I'm unclear about, since if Ubuntu was installed with wubi it needs Windows too, if it was pure dual boot installation than story is different. If you have a backup of your documents photos etc.. make clean install of ubuntu. on long term Wubi installation isn't good solution  anyway as Wubi installs Ubuntu like a new software inside Windows.

Answer (score -1):

When I started Linux first time I've also installed Windows and Ubuntu as dual-boot. As you cannot run your Ubuntu you must solve from Windows itself. I prefer to do it this way.

Install [EasyBSD (here you can find a lot of information about EasyBSD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EasyBCD)

You can download it from [this link](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) and also follow user guide on [this link](https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/dual-boot/linux/ubuntu/)

Comment: Thanks a lot ,man! Before i follow this ,is it recommended to "migrate" a wubi installed Ubuntu for it to be the main OS on my laptop (remove windows totally) ,or better to make a fresh install of Ubuntu from scratch ,using a installation cd?

Comment: For my opinion if you are going totally to integrate to linux in the future it is better to completely remove Windows and install Ubuntu to whole HDD. And if you have any special need for Windows install it on virtual machine. 
Generally for building appropriate working environment we create 3 partitions: 1 for Windows, 1 for Ubuntu and one for access from both OS.
Anyway... If you have to use Windows, first install Windows and then Ubuntu to separate partitions.  If you do it in that way you don't even need EasyBCD. Each time on boot you will be shown selection menu provided by grub.

Comment: I have backed up my data and i will just do a fresh install from Ubuntu cd ,thanks!